# PHP wont update Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a code here that won't update. If I input anything inside the input texts and press submit, the 'samp.php' will still display the original information of the database that I have updated.

codes for index.php

```
<?php
include 'connect.php';
?>
<html>
  <head>
  <title>Basic Form Handling PHP</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <?php
$result1 = $db->query("select * from chapter where chapter_id='1'");
while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1)){ echo "<form action='samp.php' method='POST'>";
 echo "     <input class='input' type='hidden' name='cid' value='{$row1['chapter_id']}'/>";
 echo "       Title: <br>";
 echo "       <input type='text' name='ctitle'><br>";
 echo "       Body: <br>";
 echo "       <input type='text' name='cbody'><br>";
 echo "       <input type='submit' name='submit' value='PRESS ME'>";
 echo "   </form>";
}
  ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

codes for connect.php

```
<?php
$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '2830775', 'unity');
?>
```

codes for samp.php

```
<?php
include 'connect.php';
?>
<?php
$id = $_POST['cid'];
$title = $_POST['ctitle'];
$body = $_POST['cbody'];
$result = $db->query("UPDATE chapter set chapter_title='$title', chapter_body='$body' where chapter_id='$id");
$result2 = $db->query("SELECT * FROM chapter where chapter_id='$id'");
?>
<?php $row1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2);
 echo $row1['chapter_body']; 

 ?>
```

Comment: it seems you did not `include 'connect.php';` in samp.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update `$result = $db->query("UPDATE chapter set chapter_title='$title', chapter_body='$body' where chapter_id='$id")` to `$result = $db->query("UPDATE chapter set chapter_title='$title', chapter_body='$body' where chapter_id='$id'")`

You forgot to end single quote there.

Comment: Thanks! You have good eyes that you even saw that!

Answer (score 1):

You need to include your connection file to your `same.php`

```
   <?php
    include 'connect.php';// incliude your connection file
    $id = $_POST['cid'];
    $title = $_POST['ctitle'];
    $body = $_POST['cbody'];
    $result = $db->query("UPDATE chapter set chapter_title='$title', chapter_body='$body' where chapter_id = '$id'");//missing Singal quote in end 
    $result2 = $db->query("SELECT * FROM chapter where chapter_id='$id'");
?>
<?php
    $row1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2);
    echo $row1['chapter_body'];

?>
```